# "hedge how ...": is this a valid collocation?

Tags: verbs

Below is an excerpt from [a New York Times story](https://www.nytimes.com/2022/12/13/world/asia/china-covid-zero-beijing.html#:%7E:text=The%20only%20sections%20with%20dwindling%20inventory%20were%20for%20cleaning%20products%20and%20booze%20as%20customers%20tried%20to%20hedge%20how%20much%20time%20they%E2%80%99d%20need%20to%20stay%20indoors.):

> The only sections with dwindling inventory were for cleaning products and booze as customers tried to **hedge how** much time they’d need to stay indoors.

I was surprised to see "hedge" used as such. I searched in Linggle and COCA; neither gave me examples that came close. Could it be a typo of the author of this article?

On the other hand, I am also wondering that, if it should not be worded "hedge how" or "hedge on/about how" (as affirmed in the results from the two corpora), what is the correct way to express it?

Comment: If you look in the dictionaries, you'll see that hedge means to limit. /how much time/ is  a self-contained phrase. to limit or hedge how much time etc. is fine. Publications like the NYT are very well edited and proofread. hedge is used in various ways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[hedge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/hedge):

> [ T + adv/prep, usually passive ]
>
> to limit something severely:
>
> *We've got permission, but it's hedged about/around with strict conditions.*

> to limit something severely:
>
> *Congressmen were warned against hedging their support for the missile program.*

Cambridge lists *hedge* as both prepositional with *about* or *around* and as non-prepositional, so both usages are valid.

If the grammar is still confusing, note that the entire phrase *how much time they'd need to stay indoors* acts as an object of the verb *hedge*, so *hedge* and *how* belong to different sentence parts - it's not really a collocation like it would be for eg. a phrasal verb (*go out*, etc.)

It's possible that the corpus prefers *hedge* with a preposition, but it's not that common of a word to use in the first place (at least, not in this meaning), so it might just be a matter of the sample being small.

Answer (score 1):

To "hedge" in this context means to balance risks. On one side, there's the risk of being indoors without cleaning supplies or alcohol. On the other side there's the risk of overspending on cleaning supplies and alcohol.

This definition from Merriam-Webster seems to apply:

> *intransitive verb*
> **3 :** to protect oneself financially

In that sentence, I they could have phrased it, "*hedge **against** how much time they’d need to stay indoors*".